# Inquiry: ARM Compatibility for Puppeteer

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, arm, puppeteer, aws-lambda-puppeteer

I'm reaching out to inquire about the compatibility of Puppeteer with ARM architecture.

I've scoured through the documentation but couldn't find any explicit mention regarding ARM compatibility.

However, before proceeding further, I wanted to confirm with the team if Puppeteer is officially supported on ARM architecture. It's crucial for our project's infrastructure planning and compatibility assurance.

Could someone please provide clarity on this matter? Any official documentation or insights regarding Puppeteer's compatibility with ARM architecture would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your attention to this matter.

To verify this, I conducted some tests by running Puppeteer within an ARM environment, specifically in a Docker container with Ubuntu as the base image. Surprisingly, Puppeteer worked seamlessly in this setup.

Comment: Hi, I think you might be confused about the purpose of this site.  It's a public community Q&A site for programming questions.  You are not contacting anybody's "team".  (Also, if by any chance you had an AI write this question, that's also not allowed on this site.)

Comment: Hi @NateEldredge apologies for that corrected it now, i used AI to re write my question nicely.

Comment: AI doesn't write very well. Avoid it. Nobody uses words like "seamlessly", "crucial", "insights", "assurance" and "conducted" except marketers.